# Circle tool stuck making ovals in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tools

I've done something to my shape tool - it's only producing ovals instead of circles, in spite of holding the shift key down.  I've found that it's also making parallelograms out of squares - skewing the objects.

I've tried to get a screen grab for you showing the cursor - as this looks different, but Snagit isn't having it, so what I have done is mocked up the cursor in Photoshop.  Here it is below:

[image]

Comment: Have you rebooted your machine? That fixes a lot of problems.

Comment: Maybe a keyboard issue? is this Windows or OSX?

Answer (score 2):

If whenever you are drawing flat shapes they skew, it sounds like you may be drawing on a perspective grid.  Turn it off by selecting View menu > Perspective Grid > Hide Grid

Answer (score 0):

I found what my problem is.  I had somehow with quick keys generated this:

[image]

Not are exactly what it is but but the problem went away when I close this 'thing'.

Comment: That is the perspective grid... Exactly as the previous answer said.